# How to use a mapped value in a function call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a  map function rendering potential trade options but I need to pass the `id` to a function when it is clicked (current code doesn't log anything). Code below:

```js
<div>{
    this.state.yourDrams.map((dram) =>
        <OfferTile
            key={dram.name}
            img={dram.image}
            name={dram.name}
            size={dram.size}
            onClick={ () => console.log(dram.id) }
        />
    )
}</div>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Here is the offerTile component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import "./offerTile.css"

export default class offerTile extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="offer">
                {this.props.img === undefined ? null : <img alt="offer" width="120" src={this.props.img}/>}
                <span><h3>{this.props.name}</h3> - <em>{this.props.dist}</em> {this.props.abv !== undefined ? <p>{this.props.abv}%</p> : null}</span>
                <p>{this.props.desc}</p>
                <p><strong>{this.props.size}</strong></p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your offertile component please. You are passing onClick prop to that component, are you handling it there?

Comment: Your code looks fine. If you share more of your code (what yourDrams looks like) we may have an easier time helping you

Comment: agreeing with @AjeetShah here, you probably just don't handle the `onClick` callback inside of the `OfferTile` component

Comment: Added the Component as requested

Comment: I would add the onClick on the div in offerTile component instead. If you want to you could pass a method from the parent and call it or handle everything inside offerTile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your looks great. I think it needs some modification.

```
<div>{
    this.state.yourDrams.map((dram) =>
        <OfferTile
            key={dram.name}
            img={dram.image}
            name={dram.name}
            size={dram.size}
            onHandleClick={ () => console.log(dram.id) }
        />
    )
}</div>
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import "./offerTile.css"

export default class offerTile extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="offer" onClick={this.props.onHandleClick}>
                {this.props.img === undefined ? null : <img alt="offer" width="120" src={this.props.img}/>}
                <span><h3>{this.props.name}</h3> - <em>{this.props.dist}</em> {this.props.abv !== undefined ? <p>{this.props.abv}%</p> : null}</span>
                <p>{this.props.desc}</p>
                <p><strong>{this.props.size}</strong></p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

You should handle onHandleClick in offerTile Component. Best practice is that not to use built-in event function as your own props name.

Comment: Feel Free to ask me anytime.